# about Synplify VHDL (code imported from Xilinx ISE)

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I'm start to work with Synopsys Synplify. Import my Xilinx ISE project (fully work).

Try to run and receive - "No matching overload for to_integer" for this line

```
rgb(7 downto 0) <= color_lut(result_reg(to_integer(unsigned(x(2 downto 0))-1 )));
```

What can I do to adopt this piece for Synplify?

Comment: Can you specify what libraries and packages you have referenced in your design? For example, library ieee; use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; etc...

Comment: Also specifying the version of Synplify could also be helpful.

Comment: Sure,library IEEE, ieee_proposed;  ----  
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;   ----
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;      ---- 
    use ieee_proposed.fixed_pkg.all; ----

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the following libraries in synplify:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.fixed_pkg.all;
```

Under implementation options > VHDL Tab make sure you enable "VHDL 2008" checkbox. I don't think it is enabled by default. This could be your problem.